# Python - left and right shifting long numbers giving unexpected results

Tags: python, python-3.x, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I have the following

```
a = 340282366920938463463374607431768211455
b = 127
print(a >> b)
```

This comes out with a value of 1 but I'm not sure why. Any advice? Am I doing it right and the result is to be expected?

Specifically the ask is:

```
Shift A, right by B, where:

A = 340282366920938463463374607431768211455
B = 127
```

Answer (score 7):

That's the expected result. 340282366920938463463374607431768211455 is, in bits, a series of 128 '1's. If you right-shift it by 127 places, 127 of those '1's are removed leaving just, well, '1'.

If you want to see it in action, try using python's `bin()` function e.g.

```py
a = 340282366920938463463374607431768211455
b = 127
print(bin(a)) // '0b1111.....'
print(len(bin(a))) // 130 (including '0b', so its actually 128)
print(bin(a >> b)) // '0b1'
```